# Separate files ,and return a constant pointers of class

Tags: pointers, header

I different classes , which are these (book, library , system) ,
Library class contain a set (Array) of books pointer type (not objects), I want to send one of these pointer for example to the system class with a costant and refernce ( const * book & ) , and keep the only functions that available to call from this book pointer (Getters function only) no setters , so I can do this with more saftey , when I do this logic without separate my codes in header files , and inclunde for example in system implementation (inclide"book.h") ( in system class functions ) the copy that I send from book can be change using setters , !!! I don't understand why such a thing is occuring

I tryied to make a constant pointer , I tryied not to include even book.h , but when I do such a thing it's impossible for system class to recgnoize what I'm talking about , when I ask for anything to do with this book argument